# Postman issue The JSON value could not be converted to agsamplewebapi.Model.Employee

Tags: c#, asp.net-core, asp.net-web-api

I'm developing ASP. NET Core web api application which will be exposed to Angular 6

After developing web api Post request , I proceeded to PostMan to check the Post request which gets an error  of  **"The JSON value could not be converted to agsamplewebapi.Model.Employee. Path: $ | LineNumber: 0 | BytePositionInLine: 1."**

**Model Code**

```
 public class Employee
  {
    public int Id { get; set; }
    public string Eno { get; set; }
    public string Ename { get; set; }
    public decimal Salary { get; set; }
    public string Gender { get; set; }
    public string Designation { get; set; }
  }
```

**Controller Code**

```
[EnableCors("CorsPolicy")]
  [Route("api/[controller]")]
  [ApiController]
  public class EmployeesController : ControllerBase
  {
    private readonly EmployeeContext _context;

    public EmployeesController(EmployeeContext context)
    {
      _context = context;
    }
    // POST: api/Employees
    [HttpPost]
    public async Task<ActionResult<Employee>> PostEmployee(Employee employee)
    {
      _context.Employee.Add(employee);
      await _context.SaveChangesAsync();

      return CreatedAtAction("GetEmployee", new { id = employee.Id }, employee);
    }

 }
```

when using Postman with https://localhost:44333/api/Employees with below listed body with Json selected error will be displayed under Postman window **"The JSON value could not be converted to agsamplewebapi.Model.Employee. Path: $ | LineNumber: 0 | BytePositionInLine: 1."**

```
[
    {    
        "Eno": "112",
        "Ename": "zzz",
        "Salary": 1888.00,
        "Gender": "M",
        "Designation": "gghh"
    }
]
```

**Provide me suiatble guide to resove this issue**

Comment: try to delete ``[ ]`` from the json?

Comment: @Sajid  answer is correct , move this to Answer Question section , will close question

Comment: i'm adding the answer, you can also change the signature of the action without changing the Json, but i think you need one object.

Answer (score 3, accepted):

You have two solutions for fixing the issue:

1 - Delete `[]` from the `Json`, like my comment:

```
{    
   "Eno": "112",
   "Ename": "zzz",
   "Salary": 1888.00,
   "Gender": "M",
   "Designation": "gghh"
}
```

2 - `[]` means a collection, then you can change the action signature, without  changing the `Json` to:

```
public async Task<ActionResult<Employee>> PostEmployee(IEnumerable<Employee> employee)
{}
```